# How to use sed to remove all double quotes within a file

Tags: sed

I have a file called file.txt.  It has a number of double quotes throughout it.  I want to remove all of them.

I have tried `sed 's/"//g' file.txt`

I have tried `sed -s "s/^\(\(\"\(.*\)\"\)\|\('\(.*\)'\)\)\$/\\3\\5/g" file.txt`

Neither have worked.

How can I just remove all of the double quotes in the file?

Comment: Your first attempt should work on a plain ASCII file. Maybe the file you're working on contains Unicode " instead?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You just need to escape the quote in your first example:

```
$ sed 's/\"//g' file.txt
```

Comment: I ran this, on the screen it flew by the thousands of entries and the quotes were gone.  Within the file.txt though, the quotes were still there.

Comment: Yes, `sed` directs output to standard out by default and does not touch the input file. If you want the output saved to a file, do `sed 's/\"//g' file.txt > file_new.txt` and then when you are happy with file_new.txt, delete the old file and rename the new one.

Comment: Or if your `sed` supports the `-i` option, that should let you replace the file with the edited file as well.

Answer (score 37):

Are you sure you need to use sed?  How about:

```
tr -d "\""
```

Comment: What if all the kinds of quotes needed to be removed? What if it needed to work with unicode also?

Answer (score 16):

For replacing in place you can also do:

```
sed -i '' 's/\"//g' file.txt
```

or in Linux

```
sed -i 's/\"//g' file.txt
```

Comment: why does the first one (unix/mac os?) need the empty single quotes as first arg?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
sed -i -e 's/\"//g' file.txt
```

Comment: Hi Amita. Thanks for your answer. But please add an explanation. How does your solution work?.  [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Additional comment.  Yes this works:

```
    sed 's/\"//g' infile.txt  > outfile.txt
```

(however with batch gnu sed, will just print to screen)

In batch scripting (GNU SED), this was needed:

```
    sed 's/\x22//g' infile.txt  > outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try prepending the doublequote with a backslash in your expresssion:

```
sed 's/\"//g' [file name]
```

Comment: I ran this, on the screen it flew by the thousands of entries and the quotes were gone.  Within the file.txt though, the quotes were still there.

Comment: I run this with csv file and all data is gone. I tired couple times with the same result.

Comment: use sed -i 's/\"//g' [file name]